# Mock BlobClient for Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, azure-blob-storage, moq

I have an Azure Function that has a blob trigger, in my function method args I expose the Blob itself via BlobClient and the name of the file uploaded.

```
[FunctionName("MyFunc")]
public async Task RunAsync([BlobTrigger("upload/{name}", Connection = "DataLake")]
                            BlobClient blob, string name)
{
    var propertiesResponse = await blob.GetPropertiesAsync();
    var properties = propertiesResponse.Value;
    var metadata = properties.Metadata;

    //do stuff with metadata
                
    if (metadata.TryGetValue("activityId", out var activityId))
    {

    }

    using (var stream = await blob.OpenReadAsync())
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        //do some stuff with blob
    }
}
```

I would like to unit test this function and was trying to mock BlobClient but having issues using the Moq library. I have found [BlobsModelFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobsmodelfactory.blobdownloadinfo?view=azure-dotnet) that aims to help mocking but I can't see anything for BlobClient.  Has anyone managed to mock BlobClient?

Comment: What issues? Most methods are virtual so it could be mocked that way.

Comment: You mean create my own type and inherit from BlobClient?

Comment: No, i mean they can be mocked using moq.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In line with the new [Azure SDK guidelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/unit-testing-and-mocking/#service-clients) public methods are marked `virtual` so they can be mocked:

> A service client is the main entry point for developers in an Azure SDK library. Because a client type implements most of the “live” logic that communicates with an Azure service, it’s important to be able to create an instance of a client that behaves as expected without making any network calls.
>
> 1. Each of the Azure SDK clients follows mocking guidelines that allow their behavior to be overridden:
> 2. Each client offers at least one protected constructor to allow inheritance for testing.
>    All public client members are virtual to allow overriding.

In case of the `BlobClient` mocking can be done like this*:

```cs
var mock = new Mock<BlobClient>();
    var responseMock = new Mock<Response>();
    mock
        .Setup(m => m.GetPropertiesAsync(null, CancellationToken.None).Result)
        .Returns(Response.FromValue<BlobProperties>(new BlobProperties(), responseMock.Object))
```

A lot of stuff, like BlobProperties, can be mocked using the static class [`BlobsModelFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobsmodelfactory?view=azure-dotnet), some examples:

```cs
var blobProps = BlobsModelFactory.BlobProperties(blobType: BlobType.Block);
var result = BlobsModelFactory.BlobDownloadResult(content: null);
```

Additional references:

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/core/Azure.Core/README.md#mocking
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/core/Azure.Core/samples/Mocking.md

**Code is for demonstration only, the references give clues on how to use BlobsModelFactory*

Comment: Thanks, on the blob client I've tried, `var mock = new Mock<BlobClient>(new BlobClient(new Uri("https://somblob.windows.net/blob/TEST"), default));` but reading back the Uri property throws a null ref exception but I can't see why. Any ideas?

Comment: Works like so  - `_blob.SetupGet(cl => cl.Uri).Returns( new Uri(BlobUri));` not sure why setting the object with constructor args isn't obeyed but this will do

Comment: The methods of `BlobClient` are virtual, this is fine. But how do I create the actual results?

Even in your example you use `new BlobProperties()` which you can create but can't set anything on it. Neither is virtual or writable. Same with other responses like `BlobDownloadResult`

Comment: @VitaliyGorbenko see updated answer that references the `BlobsModelFactory` class

Comment: FWIW, for mocking response.Headers I had to refer to this github item in the AzureSDK repo, '[QUERY] How to mock Azure.Core.ResponseHeaders'  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/18863